# ESRI ArcGIS Javascript API RelationshipQuery class

Tags: javascript, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I am having trouble with the ESRI ArcGIS Javascript API RelationshipQuery class.

I am trying to grab field(s) from a different GIS layer (in this case layer 1) in my GIS Service using the RelationshipQuery class. In other words, I want grab records with the same SCTM field in layer 1 as the SCTM field in the assessorLayer FeatureLayer object for the clicked point so I can populate all of the information into ONE pop-up window.

**This is my code segment regarding the RelationshipQuery class**

```
var title, content, graphicAttributes;

        var relatedQuery = new RelationshipQuery();
        relatedQuery.relationshipId = 1;
        relatedQuery.outFields = ["*"];


        assessorLayer.on("click", function(evt) 
        { /* start assessorLayer.on click event */

            graphicAttributes = evt.graphic.attributes;  

            title = "Assessor";
            content = "<b>Name: </b>" + graphicAttributes.OWNER_NAME + graphicAttributes.OWNER_NAME2
                    + "<br><b>Dimensions: </b>" + graphicAttributes.DIMENSIONS
                    + "<br><b>Garbage District: </b>" + graphicAttributes.CBA;

            relatedQuery.definitionExpression = ("SCTM = " + graphicAttributes.SCTM);

            assessorLayer.queryRelatedFeatures(relatedQuery, function(relatedRecords) 
            { /* start assessorLayer.queryRelatedFeatures function */
               var status = relatedRecords[graphicAttributes.STATUS];

                content = content + "<br><hr><br> Status: " + status; 


                map.infoWindow.setTitle(title);
                map.infoWindow.setContent(content);
                map.infoWindow.show(evt.screenPoint, map.getInfoWindowAnchor(evt.screenPoint));*/

            }); /* End assessorLayer.queryRelatedFeatures function */


        }); /* End assessorLayer.on click event */
```

Answer (score 1):

You need top set the objectid for the relationship query, so in the assessorLayer.on("click", function(evt) handler you can add

```
relatedQuery.objectIds = [evt.features[0].attributes.OBJECTID];
```

Another option is to use the popup template related fields syntax so that the popup automatically queries the related table for the feature and populates itself accordingly. The [JS API documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/popup_relatedrecords.html) has examples of this